# Результат сложения каждого элемента массива со всеми другими по очереди

Tags: javascript

есть `let arr = [val1, val2, val3, val4]`
мне нужен результат сложения в виде массива для каждого val c каждым  val1 + val2, val1 +val3.... потом val2+val1, val2+ val3.... и так далее
val это number

Вот примерно такой я хочу получить результат. Внизу псевдо-код. Рабочий вариант у меня не вышло сделать

```
let arr = [val1, val2, val3, val4].map((item) => {
return {
    [val1 + val2, val1 + val3, val1 +val4],
    [val2 + val1, val2 + val3, val2 + val4],
    [val3 + val1, val3 + val2, val3 + val4],
    [val4 + val1, val4 + val2, val4 + val3]
```

}
})

Comment: нужен - сделайте. что именно вызвало у Вас проблему ? обычный перебор не пробовали? и куда должен выводиться результат ?

Comment: *... потом 4+3, 4+ 2 ...* - `4+3, 4+4, 4+2, 4+5, 4+6` или `4+3, 4+2, 4+5, 4+6` ?

Comment: добавь конечный результат для приведенного тобой массива. Чтобы было видно, что ты хочешь получить в итоге

Comment: Улучшил описание, надеюсь так будет понятней!

Answer (score 0):

```js
let arr = [3, 4, 2, 5, 6];
arr.forEach(function(v, k) {
  let sum = v;
  arr.forEach(function(v2, k2) {
    sum += v2;
  });
  console.log(sum);
});
```